# Lync server mobility check response: No response received for Web-ticket service

Tags: mobile-devices, external-connection, lync-2013

I've deployed simple lync 2013 infrastracture. 
1 edge, 2 front end, 1 webapp, 1 backend for mssql databases, and AD + CC.

Everything works great except mobility.

When I run Test-CsUcwaConference, Test-CsMcxP2PIM commands following error message displayed:

[image]

IIS -> Lync server external and internal web site authentications enabled providers are Negotiate, NTLM.

Please advice me if you have happened this error too.

Answer (score 2):

*I just realized how long ago you asked this question, but since I'm already done writing an answer, I'll submit it anyway.*

The `Test-CsClientAuthentication` command works similarly to the two you referenced, but it's kind of picky about the `userSipAddress` and `UserCredential`. Especially where contoso.com doesn't equal contoso.local in my example below.

Running the following type of command will probably work, but changing `UserCredential` to the UPN results in the error you have shown above.  (No response received for Web-Ticket service. Inner Exception: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'.)

```
Test-CsClientAuthentication -TargetFqdn lyncfe.contoso.local -UserSipAddress "sip:my.name@contoso.com" -UserCredential "contoso\user"
```